# AngularJS Ng-model-options not able to select object in getter-setter function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem selecting an object from `ng-model` with `ng-model-options` and getter-setter function. I am binding to the `ng-model` getter-setter function `setGetSelectedItem` which has to accept an object from `ng-options` - in my case, `item` and to assign its properies to the properties of another object `specific_data`. It does, the object is passed correctly but I am not able to select the option in the select options.

```
<select name="item" ng-model="setGetSelectedItem"
        ng-options="item as item.title for item in items"
        ng-model-options="{getterSetter: true}">
  <option value="">-- Please select --</option>
</select>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.items = [{

"description": "Item description",
  "item_type": "OUT",
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Default item"
}];

$scope._objectDataRaw = {
  specific_data: {}
};

$scope.setGetSelectedItem = function(value) {

if (arguments.length) {
  $scope._objectDataRaw.specific_data.property_id = value.id;
  $scope._objectDataRaw.specific_data.property_title = value.title;
  $scope._objectDataRaw.specific_data.property_description = 
  value.description;

   return $scope._objectDataRaw.specific_data; 
 }
};
```

Here is a jsfiddle with the problem:
[Can not select the object](https://jsfiddle.net/mb7wp5z3/13/)

And I need it to pass it as an object, and not as object.property.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `getterSetter` option, use the [`ng-change` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) to set the `specific_data` object:

```
<select name="item" ng-model="selectedItem"
        ng-options="item as item.title for item in items"
        ̶n̶g̶-̶m̶o̶d̶e̶l̶-̶o̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶s̶=̶"̶{̶g̶e̶t̶t̶e̶r̶S̶e̶t̶t̶e̶r̶:̶ ̶t̶r̶u̶e̶}̶"̶
        ng-change="setSelectedItem(selectedItem)" >
  <option value="">-- Please select --</option>
</select>
```

[The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/hBsjDEgkhcpisljU0dr9?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
 
      "description": "Item description",
      "item_type": "OUT",
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Default item"
    }];
    
    $scope._objectDataRaw = {
      specific_data: {}
    };
    
    $scope.setSelectedItem = function(value) {
      $scope._objectDataRaw.specific_data.property_id = value.id;
      $scope._objectDataRaw.specific_data.property_title = value.title;
      $scope._objectDataRaw.specific_data.property_description = 
      value.description;
    };
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <select name="item" ng-model="selectedItem"
        ng-options="item as item.title for item in items"
        ng-change="setSelectedItem(selectedItem)" >
      <option value="">-- Please select --</option>
    </select> 
    <hr>
    _objectDataRaw={{_objectDataRaw}}
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your code should be:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
      .controller('Ctrl1', function($scope) {

        $scope.items = [{
          "description": "Item description",
          "item_type": "OUT",
          "id": 1,
          "title": "Default item"
        }];
        
        $scope._objectDataRaw = {
          specific_data: {}
        };
        
        $scope.setGetSelectedItem = function(value) {
          if (arguments.length) {
          
            $scope._objectDataRaw.specific_data.property_id = value.id;
            $scope._objectDataRaw.specific_data.property_title = value.title;
            $scope._objectDataRaw.specific_data.property_description = value.description;
            
            return $scope._objectDataRaw.specific_data;
          }
        };
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl1">
      <div>
        <select name="item" ng-repeat="item in items">
          <option value="">-- Please select --</option>
          <option value="" ng-click="setGetSelectedItem(item)">{{item.title}}</option>
        </select> 
      </div>
    </div>
```